# How can I efficiently scale CPU-intensive tasks using BullMQ Queue and child processes while overcoming limitations with object passing?

Tags: node.js, child-process, bull, bullmq

I am utilizing a machine learning (ML) object for object detection in images and have incorporated the use of the bullMQ queue.

During testing on a few hundred images, I encountered slow performance and therefore attempted to enhance its concurrency. To achieve this, I took advantage of bullMQ's sandbox process feature, which spawns child processes specifically designed for CPU-intensive tasks.

However, a predicament arises when dealing with the ML model loaded from disk, as it exists within an object. Unfortunately, I am unable to pass this object to the child processes, necessitating the need to reload the ML object. This approach not only increases disk utilization but also introduces the potential for bottlenecks.

I am seeking guidance on potential workarounds for this issue. Am I overlooking something or mismanaging the situation? Additionally, I am curious to understand the methodologies employed in scaling and executing CPU-intensive tasks effectively.

Comment: Your OS should already be read-caching anything that you read from disk frequently.  It's not clear to me that this is a problem you actually need to solve.